# Graphite: aggregation method for counters

Tags: graphite

I am going to put an ever increasing counter value into Graphite.  I'm not sure what I should use for the aggregation method.  I think it would either be "min" or "max".  The default of "average" doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Would it make more sense to make it a rate of change gauge?

Comment: I cannot change the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you're looking for with any of the storage aggregations, which are rather limited, but you can display what you're after with the `derivative()` function at render-time.